# "Arguments to path.join must be strings" issue

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm trying to use grunt sass to compile my css files, and here is the Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            grunt: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },

            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
}
```

However, it always return the error below when I use "grunt" command to watch it and make changes to any sass file in sass/ directory.

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings Use --force to continue.
```

Is there any way I can fix it? It's string already.

Comment: I think you need to remove the array from css tasks, so it's just `tasks:'sass'` instead of `tasks: ['sass']`

Comment: Hi @TonyBarnes Still the same issue.

Comment: Which version of 'grunt-contrib-sass' ?

Comment: @SatyamKoyani I think it should be the latest one, how can I check it?

Comment: try 'npm list' and check it

Comment: @Darklizard Try defining the sass files/paths with the `expand` property?: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#user-content-compile-files-in-a-directory

Comment: @SatyamKoyani it's 0.4.0

Comment: Try Switching back to 0.3.0 works.

Answer (score 1):

Here uninstall your `0.4.0` version of `grunt-contrib-sass` by running below command.

```
npm uninstall grunt-contrib-sass
```

Now, Install `0.3.0` version of `grunt-contrib-sass` by executing below command.

```
npm install grunt-contrib-sass@0.3.0
```

Hope It will work.

You can see [issue logged here regarding this.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/issues/49)